# Probability of finding a non-defective transistor when selecting 3 transistors out of 10 transistors .

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Question:

> A box contains 10 transistors, of which 3 are defective. A transistor
> is selected from the box and tested until a non-defective one is
> chosen. If X is the number of transistors to be chosen. Find P(X = 3).

My attempt:

Since we keep testing until we find a non-defective one, then we need to select **at least 1 non-defective transistor** in our **3 tests**.

then $P(X = 3) = $ $${7 \choose 1}{3 \choose 2} + {7 \choose 2}{3 \choose 1} \over {10 \choose 3}$$ = **7/10**

However, final answer = **7/120**, which contradicts my answer, and I'm quite confused.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stop when you pick a non-defective transistor. So for $X = 3$, the first two must be defective one's.

So the probability is,

$P(X = 3) =  \displaystyle \frac{3}{10} \cdot \frac{2}{9} \cdot \frac{7}{8} = \frac{7}{120}$

Or the way you calculated, it should be

$ \displaystyle \frac {2! \cdot {3 \choose 2}{7 \choose 1} }{ 3! \cdot {10 \choose 3}} = \frac{7}{120}$

You choose two defective one's that can be arranged in the first and second place. The third place is fixed for the non-defective transistor. The denominator is arrangements of any three chosen transistors.

Comment: Is it me, or it wasn't really clear that the question was asking me to stop when selecting the first non-defective transistor? Anyways, thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: @AmirWG may be the question could be more clear. I interpreted based on the part which says _until a non-defective one is chosen_